# Limit of $ \frac{1}{2}\frac{\sin^2(\omega t/2)}{(\omega/2)^2}$

Tags: limits, limsup-and-liminf, dirac-delta

I'm trying to prove that

$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2}\frac{\sin^2(\omega t/2)}{(\omega/2)^2} = \pi \delta(\omega) t $

Any thoughts on how could I do that?
I thought about mapping it to the identity $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x}=\pi$ but I did not succeed.

Thanks.

Comment: There is not limit: the image of $\{\omega t \mid t>0\}$ in $\mathbf R/2\pi\mathbf Z$ is dense.

Comment: @Bernard The equality cannot be correct as written (with the rhs still dependent on $t$), but the distributional limit $\lim_{t \to \infty} \sin^2(\omega t/2)/(2 t (\omega/2)^2)$ exists and is equal to $\pi \delta(\omega)$.

Comment: @Maxim Could you provide any reference where this is derived? I really appreciate.

Comment: I don't have a reference for this particular formula. It can be derived by taking $u = t \omega$ and showing that $f(t, u) = 2 \sin^2(u/2) \phi(u/t)/u^2$ is uniformly bounded by an integrable function and that $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(t, u)$ exists, which implies
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb R} f(t, u) du =
\int_{\mathbb R} \lim_{t \to \infty} f(t, u) du.$$
Delta sequences in general are discussed in any book on the theory of distributions.